# Service worker not activated in Puppeteer for localhost domain

Tags: https, puppeteer, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The service worker I'm talking about here is from a chrome extension (background script).
Because it is the background script from a chrome extension, it gets loaded into the browser as follows

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: false,
        args: [
            `--disable-extensions-except=${EXTENSION_PATH}`,
            `--load-extension=${EXTENSION_PATH}`,
            '--user-agent=PuppeteerAgent',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--user-data-dir="./tmp/"'
            // '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
       ],
    });

    const appPage = await browser.newPage();
    await appPage.goto('https://google.com', { waitUntil: 'load' });

    const targets = await browser.targets();

    const extensionTarget = targets.find((target: any) => target.type() === 'service_worker');

   const partialExtensionUrl = (extensionTarget as any)._targetInfo.url || '';
   ....
```

This snippet works fine as long as I have an https url. When I use `http://localhost:8000` the service worker is not activated and `extensionTarget` is undefined.

I think this makes sense. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers):

> These days, service workers are enabled by default in all modern browsers. To run code using service workers, you'll need to serve your code via HTTPS — Service workers are restricted to running across HTTPS for security reasons. GitHub is therefore a good place to host experiments, as it supports HTTPS. In order to facilitate local development, localhost is considered a secure origin by browsers as well.

So, the service worker will work if it is served via https or from `localhost`. I get the impression that because it is a chrome extension, the localhost rule does not apply here. So my question is, is there a way to fix this or disable this restriction (unfortunately `--disable-web-security` didn't do the trick)

Any help would be appreciated